# after inserting to a linked list, the value head value is the last value entered. why?

Tags: c++, generics, linked-list

i have a generic linked list struct like this

```
template <typename E, typename F>
struct node
{
public:
    E data;
    node<E, F>* next;
    node<F, F>* down;
};
```

and one class like this

```
class LetterList
{
private:
    node <char, Dictionary> *head;
public:
    LetterList(){head = NULL;};
    void createLetterList();
    void print();
};
```

the Dictionary in "node  *head;" is another class;
what i would like to do is insert all the alphabets in to linked list using the LetterList class. Here is the code i have for that..

```
node <char, Dictionary> *p = new node <char, Dictionary>;
    p->data = 'A';
    char ch;
    if (head == NULL)
        {
            p->next = NULL;
            head = p;
        }

    node <char, Dictionary> *q = head;

    while (true)
    {
        for (int i=66; i<91;i++)
        {
            ch = char (i);
            p->data = ch;
            q ->next = p;
            if (i == 90)
            {
                q->next = NULL;
            }
            else
                q = q->next;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

after executing this code the head of the linked list is 'Z', but shouldn't it be 'A'? please tell me what i have done wrong in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only allocating one node.  IF you want to have nodes 'A' to 'Z' in the list then you need to allocate a new node anytime to add it to the list.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by jcopenha, you are not creating new node dynamically. You just pointed 'q' to head and keep updating its data with A, B, C,... and so on until Z. Following update to the code should work:

```
while (true)
{
    node <char, Dictionary> *temp;
    temp = NULL;
    p -> next = temp;
    for (int i=66; i<91;i++)
    {
        ch = char (i);
        node <char, Dictionary> *z = new node <char, Dictionary>;
        z->data = ch;
        temp = z;
        temp->next = NULL;
        temp = temp->next;       
    }
    break;
}
```